# Save Scrapy 'start_urls' and store properly in a Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scrapy

I am using Scrapy to scrape some website data. But I can't make the step to get my data properly.

This is the output of my code (see code below):

In the command Line:

```
scrapy crawl myspider -o items.csv
```

Output:

```
asin_product                                    product_name
ProductA,,,ProductB,,,ProductC,,,            BrandA,,,BrandB,,,BrandC,,,    

ProductA,,,ProductD,,,ProductE,,,            BrandA,,,BrandB,,,BrandA,,,    

#Note that the rows are representing the start_urls and that the ',,,' 
#three commas are separating the data.
```

Desired output:

```
scrapy crawl myspider -o items.csv

Start_URL     asin_product      product_name 
URL1           ProductA           BrandA
URL1           ProductB           BrandB
URL1           ProductC           BrandC
URL2           ProductA           BrandA
URL2           ProductD           BrandB
URL2           ProductE           BrandA
```

My Used Code in Scrapy:

```
import scrapy
from amazon.items import AmazonItem

class AmazonProductSpider(scrapy.Spider):
  name = "AmazonDeals"
  allowed_domains = ["amazon.com"]

#Use working product URL below
   start_urls = [
      "https://www.amazon.com/s?k=shoes&ref=nb_sb_noss_2",   # This should 
       be #URL 1       
      "https://www.amazon.com/s?k=computer&ref=nb_sb_noss_2" # This should 
       be #URL 2 
 ]

def parse(self, response):

  items = AmazonItem()

  title = response.xpath('//*[@class="a-size-base-plus a-color-base a- 
  text-normal"]/text()').extract()
  asin =  response.xpath('//*[@class ="a-link-normal"]/@href').extract()  

  # Note that I devided the products with ',,,' to make it easy to separate 
  # them. I am aware that this is not the best approach. 
  items['product_name'] = ',,,'.join(title).strip()
  items['asin_product'] = ',,,'.join(asin).strip()

  yield items
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it's [recomended to use css when querying by class](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#when-querying-by-class-consider-using-css).

Now to your code:

The product name is within the a tag (product url). So you can iterate though the links and store the URL and the title.

```
<a class="a-link-normal a-text-normal" href="/adidas-Mens-Lite-Racer-Running/dp/B071P19D3X/ref=sr_1_3?keywords=shoes&amp;qid=1554132536&amp;s=gateway&amp;sr=8-3">
    <span class="a-size-base-plus a-color-base a-text-normal">Adidas masculina Lite Racer byd tênis de corrida</span>
</a>
```

You need to create one `AmazonItem` object per line on your csv file.

```
def parse(self, response):

    # You need to improve this css selector because there are links which
    # are not a product, this is why I am checking if title is None and continuing.
    for product in response.css('a.a-link-normal.a-text-normal'):
        # product is a selector
        title = product.css('span.a-size-base-plus.a-color-base.a-text-normal::text').get()
        if not title:
            continue
        # The selector is already the a tag, so we only need to extract it's href attribute value.
        asin =  product.xpath('./@href').get()

        item = AmazonItem()
        item['product_name'] = title.strip()
        item['asin_product'] = asin.strip()

        yield item
```

Comment: Thanks @Luiz! It is working, but two small remarks: 
1). Is it possible to see the URL's? Just like the example, an extra column with the URL's? 

2). I think you forgot a ' at this line:         asin =  product.xpath('./@href).get() # at leas, I added the comma after href. 

3). When executing, the values are saved in a CSV file, but not sure why.. but every after every row, there is an empty row. Is that because of the "if not title continue"?

Many thanks!!

Comment: @Roverflow  1) You can get the url that generated a response using response.url. So you can do item['url'] = response.url. 2) Yes, I forgot a '. 3) I should be related to the continue, open the csv as a text file and see how the commas are present on the file, maybe this is related to your csv viewer (excel, open(libre)office).

Answer (score 1):

1. Make the start_url available in parse method

instead of using start_urls you can yield your initial requests from a method named start_requests (see https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html?highlight=start_requests#our-first-spider).

With each request you can pass the start url as meta data. This meta data is then available within your parse method (see https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html?highlight=meta#scrapy.http.Request.meta).

```
def start_requests(self):
    urls = [...]  # this is equal to your start_urls
    for start_url in urls:
        yield Request(url=url, meta={"start_url": start_url})

def parse(self, response):
    start_url = response.meta["start_url"]
```

2. yield multiple items, one for each product

Instead of joining titles and brands you can yield several items from parse. For the example below i assume the lists title and asin have the same length.

```
for title, asin in zip(title, asin):
    item = AmazonItem()
    item['product_name'] = title
    item['asin_product'] = asin
    yield item
```

PS: you should check amazons robots.txt. They might not allow you to scrape their site and ban your IP (https://www.amazon.de/robots.txt)

Comment: Thanks for your help Raphael! But this solution is not storing the data 'properly' as in the example above, right?

Comment: I've updated my answer with an extra step for the output format @Roverflow